# Gatling is not working with SpringBoot 2.0.1.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, gatling

I'm trying to setup **Gatling** with **Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE**.

I've created this api:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public class ContactController {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity get() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Contact retrieved successfully");
    }
}
```

And this basic simulation:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class ContactSimulation extends Simulation {

  val httpConf = http.baseURL("http://localhost:8080")

  val scn = scenario("GetContact")
    .exec(
      http("GetContact")
        .get("/contact")
        .check(status.is(200))
    )

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpConf)
}
```

The **build.gradle** is configured this way:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.gatling.poc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:2.3.0')
}

task loadTest(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn testClasses
    description = "Load Test With Gatling"
    group = "Load Test"
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    jvmArgs = [
            "-Dgatling.core.directory.binaries=${sourceSets.test.output.classesDir.toString()}"
    ]
    main = "io.gatling.app.Gatling"
    args = [
            "--simulation", "com.gatling.poc.simulations.ContactSimulation",
            "--results-folder", "${buildDir}/gatling-results",
            "--binaries-folder", sourceSets.test.output.classesDir.toString(),
            "--bodies-folder", sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs.toList().first().toString() + "/gatling/bodies",
    ]
}
```

While executing the tests:

```
./gradlew loadTest
```

I'm getting the following stacktrace:

```
21:00:12.804 [main] WARN io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise - An exception was thrown by org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender$1.operationComplete()
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.newInstance()Lio/netty/channel/DefaultChannelId;
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.newId(AbstractChannel.java:111)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.<init>(AbstractChannel.java:83)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.FailedChannel.<init>(FailedChannel.java:33)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:330)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:163)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:156)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:81)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender$1.onSuccess(NettyRequestSender.java:292)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender$1.onSuccess(NettyRequestSender.java:285)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleFutureListener.java:24)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:33)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.sendRequestWithNewChannel(NettyRequestSender.java:285)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.sendRequestWithCertainForceConnect(NettyRequestSender.java:136)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.sendRequest(NettyRequestSender.java:107)
        at org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClient.execute(DefaultAsyncHttpClient.java:216)
        at org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(DefaultAsyncHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(DefaultAsyncHttpClient.java:206)
        at io.gatling.http.ahc.HttpEngine.warmpUp(HttpEngine.scala:96)
        at io.gatling.http.protocol.HttpProtocol$$anon$1.$anonfun$newComponents$1(HttpProtocol.scala:62)
        at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.comps$1(Protocol.scala:67)
        at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.$anonfun$components$4(Protocol.scala:69)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:82)
        at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.components(Protocol.scala:69)
        at io.gatling.http.action.HttpActionBuilder.lookUpHttpComponents(HttpActionBuilder.scala:25)
        at io.gatling.http.action.sync.HttpRequestActionBuilder.build(HttpRequestActionBuilder.scala:33)
        at io.gatling.core.structure.StructureBuilder.$anonfun$build$1(StructureBuilder.scala:34)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:118)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:86)
        at io.gatling.core.structure.StructureBuilder.build(StructureBuilder.scala:33)
        at io.gatling.core.structure.StructureBuilder.build$(StructureBuilder.scala:32)
        at io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder.build(ScenarioBuilder.scala:38)
        at io.gatling.core.structure.PopulationBuilder.build(ScenarioBuilder.scala:98)
        at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.$anonfun$scenarios$1(Simulation.scala:188)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:283)
        at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.scenarios(Simulation.scala:188)
        at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:95)
        at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:64)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:59)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:43)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:35)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
```

If I create the same project using **SpringBoot 1.5.12.RELEASE**, it works perfectly. I'm suspecting of the **spring-boot-gradle-plugin** since it changes according to the SpringBoot version.

If necessary I can create a project into github to demonstrate the problem. =)

I would appreciate if someone could help me!

Answer (score 0):

I got fix this issue.

The problem was the version of the **io.netty** group used by the **SpringBoot 2.0.1.RELEASE**. It is using the version **4.1.23.Final** which for some reason (maybe some change in scala) is not executing the gatling tests.

I did the downgrade to use the same version as **SpringBoot 1.5.12.RELEASE**, which is **4.0.51.Final**. I had to add this configuration to the **build.gradle**:

```
{
// This build.gradle is the same that I posted above. For the sake of simplicity I just put the configuration that has been necessary to solve the problem.

// After dependencies{} section, I had to put this:

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'io.netty') {
                details.useVersion "4.0.51.Final"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I don't think is the best solution since I'm reverting the io.netty version to use a older version, which can have some side effect. In my case I didn't have the option of downgrading the SpringBoot version. If you have the option to revert the SpringBoot version, I would recommend to do that.